# Which one must I use "see/am seeing" and what is your reason?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

> Right now I am looking at the board. I **see/am seeing** some words on the board.

Would you possibly readily or simply tell me which one? And why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general "rule" is that with *stative* verbs—verbs which express a state rather than an event, such as *know*, *love*, *see*—English doesn’t use progressive constructions.

This is because the function of the progressive is to ‘recategorize’ a non-stative verb as stative. When you say *I was writing my paper* instead of *I wrote my paper*, what you are doing is getting “inside” the event, looking at a time when you were in a *state* of writing. With stative verbs, this is unnecessary. The progressive construction doesn’t add any meaning. *I see him* means, usually, exactly the same thing as *I am seeing him*—so we use the simpler form, *saw*.

But language evolves, and people discover new uses for existing forms. Over the last century or so English has developed two sorts of new use for progressive statives:

- **to express new meanings** — When we say *John is being a jerk*, we don’t mean *John **is** a jerk*, we mean *John **is behaving like** a jerk*. When we say *John **is seeing** Mary*, we don’t mean *John **perceives** Mary*, we mean *John **is dating** Mary.*
- **to express *change* of state** (or potential change of state) — With *see*, for instance, you might hear *We’re seeing more and more students arrive in college without adequate knowledge of grammar*. This emphasizes the fact that they used to be very few such students, but now there are many: there has been a change of state, not in their ‘seeing’ but in what they see.

  Thus, you would ordinarily use  *see* to talk about what you see on your computer screen. But if you are talking to a tech support person, describing what you don’t understand or you wish would change, the two of you might very well use *seeing*: “*Click the 'Save As' button ... now, what are you seeing?*” or “*OMG, I’m seeing the Blue Screen of Death!*”

Comment: So, is it better to write: say, in this situation which I have asked, in my original question

Comment: @nima_persian Again, it depends on **context**. Are you just reporting what words are there? - then "I see". If you're reporting that the words have changed, or planning on changing them, then "I'm seeing".

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when a verb refers to passive sensory observation (like "see/hear" but not like "look/listen"), we use the present, and not the present progressive.

So

- I hear a noise.
- I see something funny.
- I smell food.
- I taste something bitter in this dish.

In all of these sentences, the present progressive makes sense, but sounds a little foreign.

Comment: I think with prepositional phrases after the subject and action, "am seeing" doesn't sound that foreign, but your point is correct without the prepositional phrases.

Comment: @DavidWilkins So "I taste" could become "I am tasting" without sounding odd, but the others *would* sound odd if the progressive were used? To my ear, all four may or may not sound odd in different contexts, but the presence or absence of a prepositional phrase seems to make no difference.

Comment: Yes! While there is nothing ungrammatical about _I am seeing_ or _I am tasting_, we just don't often express it that way. Here is a [cool Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+seeing%2CI+see%2CI+am+hearing%2CI+hear&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), if you care to see it yourself. Same goes for [smell & taste](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+tasting%2CI+taste%2CI+am+smelling%2C+I+smell&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). I'm impressed by this answer – although I've never been taught this, it seems to be true.

Answer (score -1):

I would use "I am seeing" as opposed to "I see" because the emphasis is the moment, now, and not the action, "see".