# "Know", meaning "recognize"

Tags: verbs, aspect

Here the word of **[know](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/know_1)** has the meaning of "recognize":

> I couldn't see who was speaking, but I **knew** the voice.
>
> She **knows** a bargain when she sees one.

But I think the bold **know** here is static and cannot be replaced with **recognize**.

I guess **know** here could be replaced with **be able to recognize**. Am I right?

Comment: How come bargain as a noun fits here. Is the sentence structured properly?

Comment: @MaulikV - _bargain_ in this context means _a good deal_: _Paper towels were on sale yesterday, so I bought 12 rolls. What a bargain!_

Comment: Your sentence is clear. It gives context of paper towel but in that sentence what she sees? What she knows? A bargain? Sorry. I'm operating through a smartphone so there will be typos and weird things.

Comment: @Maulik - What she sees would be context dependent. _She knows a good bargain when she sees one_ – if we are talking about a real estate agent, we might be talking about a low price on a good piece of property. If we're referring to an antique dealer, she knows when she's paying less than market value for a high-quality, coveted item. Although the words might make one curious about further context, the sentence still stands on its own.

Comment: Both are from OALD. @Maulik V http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/know_1

Comment: @J.R. I see. It looked half baked to me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right that *know* in its primary sense has a stative [*lexical aspect*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info)—it expresses an enduring state, without defined beginning or end—while *recognize* is an achievement verb, with telic, non-durative aspect.

You should be aware, however, that almost any English verb can be ‘recategorized’ to meet the needs of a particular utterance. For instance, as we have discussed [elsewhere on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19590/32), a stative verb may be recategorized as an activity verb by casting it into the progressive mode.

Likewise, stative verbs are often employed with *inchoative* aspect, in which they express not the existence but the onset of a state. That is the case with your two uses of *know*: they express the entry into a state of knowing—which happens also to be the meaning of *recognize*.

For a similar *inchoative* use of a stative, consider the verb *love*. Ordinarily we express the inchoative sense of *love* with the phrase *fall in love*; but in one of the most famous lines in English poetry (Shakespeare himself quoted it), bare *love* is used in both stative and inchoative senses:

> Whoever loved that loved not at first sight?
>        <sup>stative</sup>  <sup>inchoative</sup>

Note, too, that the opposite is also true: the achievement verb *recognize* has a common secondary sense in which it has stative aspect:

> The United Nations recognizes the family as the basic unit of society.

Comment: Maybe there is another dichotemy: the state will **last** after entry into that state or the state will **soon vanish** after entry into that state. **know** belongs to the former while **recognize** belongs to the latter.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Not really: within the bounds of any discourse, it is tacitly assumed that a state endures until it is explicitly ended. The difference is that *recognize* and inchoative *know* are 'eventive',  marking a change of state: both mean that you enter into a state of 'knowing' him, and that endures.

Comment: An idea suddenly occurs to me. Is it equivalent to use present continuous form in these **know or recognize** examples? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng No. Continuous/progressive constructions recategorize statives as *activities* (see the 'elsewhere on ELL' link above). In some respects activities and states have similar syntactic properties, which is why some linguists call the progressive a 'stativizer'.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence:

> *She knows a good bargain when she sees one*.

I think the word *know* is being used with more "depth" than mere "recognition." The sentence as a whole suggests a degree of familiarity – this is a seasoned shopper who is very acquainted with the marketplace, who understands the tricks of the trade. She seldom overpays for anything, and often gets very good deals on what she buys.

I looked up *know* in NOAD, and found several meanings. I'll put a few here – the ones I think can apply to the sentence you provided:

> - be aware of through observation, inquiry, or information
> - be familiar or acquainted with (something)
> - recognize (someone or something)
> - be able to distinguish thing from (another)

Yes, I could say:

> *She recognizes a good bargain when she sees one*.

but I don't think that's quite as good. The sentence loses a certain nuance of familiarity with that substitution.

Comment: In your example, is _recognize_ a dynamic verb? And in my example, is _know_ a static verb?

Comment: @Zhan – That's more of an ELU question. :^) Based on [this](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/stat.htm), I'd agree: _Dynamic verbs can be used in the simple and perfect forms (plays, played, has played, had played) as well as the continuous or progressive forms (is playing, was playing, has been playing). We CANNOT use static verbs in the continuous (progressive) forms; you CAN'T say "Yong is owning three cars."_ Based on that, I think _She is recognizing a good bargain every day_ seems more acceptable than _She is knowing a good bargain every day_ – but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I think I can interpret it this way - I recognize who has a certain feature, and I know that guy as well.

Answer (score 0):

rec·og·nize   (rĕk′əg-nīz′)
tr.v. rec·og·nized, rec·og·niz·ing, rec·og·niz·es
1. To know to be something that has been perceived before: recognize a face.
2. To know or identify from past experience or knowledge: recognize hostility.
3. To perceive or show acceptance of the validity or reality of: recognizes the concerns of the tenants. Collins Dictionary

Actually they can be used as synonyms... Even though I agree that in the two sentences I would replace "know", with "can recognize".

Comment: Although I **know** James I couldn't **recognize** him. How would you interchange them here? They are not same.

Comment: for instance, you mean you two only chat online? so you can't recognize him. @Maulik V

Comment: I wrote that "they can be used as synonyms" (not that they are outright synonyms) referring to the sentences stated by the OP.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng not necessary. *ah. The man in red is not Michael for sure. I know him*

Comment: Can I say I know James but I can't recognize his voice when I meet him? @Maulik V

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng certainly. In that case your chat matter can be applied.